# CURL C++ no return

Tags: c++, libcurl

I'm using curl in my C++ program, and it is returning the HTML from the webpage. But I need it to only return the status code. I'm pretty sure the function that's returning the contents is called `curl_easy_perform()`.

Long story short, I just need it to return the status code and not the content.

Here is my code.

```
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
  CURLcode res;
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com");
  res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
  if(res == CURLE_OK) {
    long response_code;
    curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &response_code);
  }
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

Comment: Perform a `HEAD` request instead of `GET`. You might need to use the full `curl` instead of `curl_easy_xxx`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, for an HTTP(S) request, `curl_easy_perform()` will perform a `GET` request, which retrieves the requested resource's headers and content.  Since you don't want the content, you should send a `HEAD` request instead, which will retrieve only the resource's headers and not its content.

Use the [`CURLOPT_NOBODY`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_NOBODY.html) option for this purpose:

> CURLOPT_NOBODY - do the download request without getting the body
>
> A long parameter set to 1 tells libcurl to not include the body-part in the output when doing what would otherwise be a download. **For HTTP(S), this makes libcurl do a HEAD request.** For most other protocols it means just not asking to transfer the body data.

For example:

```
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
  CURLcode res;
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1); // <-- ADD THIS
  res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
  if(res == CURLE_OK) {
    long response_code;
    curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &response_code);
  }
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```